# Ember: incrementProperty interaction with button and input

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a numeric property that can be changed with a button click (using incrementProperty) or through direct input with a text field.

When both are used together, the incrementProperty starts appending "1" to the end of the number instead of incrementing it.

See the problem in this [simple Ember jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jimafuqa/1/edit?html,js,output) I modified.

To reproduce:

1. Enter a number in the text field.
2. Click the **+** button.

Strangely, decrementProperty seems to work fine. If you follow the steps above and then click the **-** button, it seems to reset the value from a string to a number and both increment and decrement work fine. Similarly, if you type in a number and click the **-** button, everything works fine. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `incrementProperty` is performing a concatenation operation rather than numeric addition as the input helper sets the value as a `string`.

If you see the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/observable.js#L425) for `incrementProperty` method, you can spot the below line which is supposed to perform the increment operation.

```
set(this, keyName, (get(this, keyName) || 0) + increment);
```

This can perform numeric addition or concatenation depending on the value of the key.

`decrementProperty` works fine as `-` operator is not overloaded. For example `"22" - 1` returns 21.

A quick fix would be to perform type conversion before incrementing. I have modified code from your jsBin to print type of the value when it is changed. You can see it print `string` when you enter values using the input helper.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    age: 36,
    ageDidChange: function () {
        console.log(typeof(this.get('age')));
    }.observes('age'),
    actions: {
        older: function() {
            this.set('age', parseInt(this.get('age'), 10) + 1);
        },
        younger: function() {
            this.decrementProperty('age');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. A little more typing than the Ember methods, but more effective. :)